# Sum Barplot of a dataset in R

Tags: r, bar-chart

Lets say I have a csv dataset with 100 columns and 200 rows.

Every row is an observation and the columns are questions measured on a Likert scale(categorical) from 1-5.

Now I want to make **one** barplot with the frequency on the y-axis and the categories 1-5 on the x-axis. So in the end I just want to have a clean overview of which categories have been used most or least without any further detail.

Sorry, this must be super easy, but if I search for solutions I mostly get super fancy multiple or stacked barplots.

So basically, if * is defined as all columns I need something like:

```
barplot(dataset$*)
```

### *Additional Comment:*

When I aksed this questions the code above worked for 1 column f.e.

```
barplot(dataset$column1)
```

Then I played a bit around and suddenly the frequency now is on the x-axis and it looks all weird that way, but its the same code. How is that even possible?
[image]

If I change the code to:

```
barplot(xtabs(~dataset$column1))
```

I will get the same result as it was before:
[image]

Comment: barplot(as.numeric(dataset)) ?

Comment: You should post a smaller dataset, perhaps `dput(head(dfrm[ , 1:10]) )`

Comment: Assumptions: 100 questions, 200 respondents, data read into a data frame called `dataset` with 100 columns and 200 rows. Then `barplot(table(as.matrix(dataset)))` should give you the distribution of responses across the whole survey.

Answer (score 2):

**Barplots of two sets, side by side**

```
x <- c(0.0001, 0.0059, 0.0855, 0.4082) 
y <- c(0.54, 0.813, 0.379, 0.35) 

# create a two row matrix with x and y 
height <- rbind(x, y) 

# Use height and set 'beside = TRUE' to get pairs 
# save the bar midpoints in 'mp' 
# Set the bar pair labels to A:D 
mp <- barplot(height, beside = TRUE,  
              ylim = c(0, 1.1),  
              main="Species 8472 damage taken by Cube and Battle", 
              names.arg = c("Battle 1", "Battle 2", "Battle 3", "Battle 4"),  
              col = c("#999999", "#56B4E9")) 

legend("topleft", 
       legend = c("Cube 17", "Cube 19"), 
       fill = c("#999999", "#56B4E9")) 

# Draw the bar values above the bars 
text(mp, height, labels = format(height, 5), pos = 3, cex = .75)
```

[image: R barplot of two vectors broken out by 2 categories]

**Barplots of two sets, stacked**

```
x <- c(0.0001, 0.0059, 0.0855, 0.4082) 
y <- c(0.54, 0.813, 0.379, 0.35) 

height <- rbind(x, y) 
thesum = colSums(rbind(x, y)) 

mp <- barplot(height, beside = FALSE,  
              main="Species 8472 cumulative damage taken, by Cube and Battle", 
              ylim = c(0, 1.1),  
              names.arg = c("Battle 1", "Battle 2", "Battle 3", "Battle 4"),  
              col = c("#999999", "#56B4E9")) 

legend("topleft", 
       legend = c("Cube 17", "Cube 19"), 
       fill = c("#999999", "#56B4E9")) 
text(mp, thesum, labels = format(thesum, 5), pos = 3, cex = .75)
```

[image: R barplot of stacked vectors broken out by 2 categories]

Comment: How can I do it so that if it's not ´´´beside=TRUE´´´ then the sum of the two columns appear at the top?

Comment: Make a new vector which is the sum of the the other 2 vectors yourself then using the `text(` method to position and overlay numbers.